Create Azure monitor diagnostic setting
Well, I've had better days, I'm tied and disappointed. I've been trying to create a diagnostic setting and it hasn't been successful. I have create 1 variable for all the setting and have defaults values defined as well. My problem is the each.value.. for the resource. I'm failing rather miserably.
variables.tf
variable "activity_log" {
  description = "Azure monitor activity log alert rules for postgres server"
  type        = any

  default = {
    server_stop = {
      name        = "psqlsrv_stopped"
      description = "Alert rule if this server is stopped"

      criteria = {
        category       = "Administrative"
        operation_name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/stop/action"
        statuses       = ["Succeeded", "Failed"]
      }
    }

    server_restart = {
      name        = "psqlsrv_restarted"
      description = "Alert rule if this server is restarted"

      criteria = {
        category       = "Administrative"
        operation_name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/restart/action"
        statuses       = ["Succeeded", "Failed"]
      }
    }

    server_delete = {
      name        = "psqlsrv_deleted"
      description = "Alert rule if this server is restarted"

      criteria = {
        category       = "Administrative"
        operation_name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers/delete"
        statuses       = ["Succeeded", "Failed"]
      }
    }

    servicehealth = {
      name        = "psqlsrv_servicehealth"
      description = "Alert rule if this server has a service health alert"

      criteria = {
        category = "ServiceHealth"
        events   = ["Incident", "ActionRequired", "Security"]
      }
    }

    resourcehealth = {
      name        = "psqlsrv_servicehealth"
      description = "Alert rule if this server has a resource health alerts"

      criteria = {
        category = "ResourceHealth"
        resource_health = {
          current  = ["Degraded", "Unavailable", "Unknown"]
          previous = ["Available"]
          reason   = ["PlatformInitiated", "UserInitiated", "Unknown"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

main.tf
resource "azurerm_monitor_activity_log_alert" "alert_rule" {
  for_each = var.activity_log

  name                = each.value["name"]
  description         = each.value["description"]
  scopes              = [azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.postgres_server.id]
  resource_group_name = element(var.rgname, 1)

  criteria {
    category       = each.value.criteria.category
    operation_name = each.value.criteria.operation_name
    statuses       = each.value.criteria.statuses

    service_health {
      events = each.value.service_health.events
    }

    resource_health {
      current  = each.value.resource_health.current
      previous = each.value.resource_health.previous
      reason   = each.value.resource_health.reason
    }
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = data.azurerm_monitor_action_group.action_group.id
  }

  tags = local.project_tags
}


Create azure monitor diagnostic setting

Are you basically trying to create a diagnostic setting? Could you please clarify. @user23350878

Yes that is correct I'm trying to create a diagnostic settings.

For what are all the logs and metrics you are trying to create a diagnostic setting? Can you brief here in a clear way. @user23350878

Sorry my question was misleading; long night. I'm trying to create an activity log alert, not a diagnostic settings. I want alerts for server restarts, stops and delete. I also want alerts on resource and service health.

Yes, now I understand the requirement. Will update you shortly. @user23350878

Hi, I have been waiting to see if you had an update, I didn't want to bother those already helping me. I just wanted you to know that I'm waiting. Thanks.
